# Logical-operators exercise in Python

Tags: python

really struggling with this simple problem below.
struggling to code a line of code that include all the possible cases.

any suggestion would be much appreciated

the code has to print True if

`feel_prepared = True`

and

`review_time > = 2`

But if `test_percent >=20` than we need a `review_time` of at least 4 hours to get a TRUE

```
test_percent = 21
review_time = 2
feel_prepared = True
```

```
print(prepared and (test_percent >= 20 or test_percent <20) and review_time >=4))
```

but doesn't work if `feel_prepared = True`, `review_time = 2` and `test_percentage \<20`

Comment: `test_percent >= 20 or test_percent <20` is always true.

Comment: Typo? `>=4` should be `>=2`. `prepared` should be `feel_prepared`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to break this problem into smaller ones, and solve it iteratively.

Let's review the first part of the exercise:

> the code has to print True if
> feel_prepared = True
> and
> review_time > = 2

So you pass the test when `feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 2`.

Now for the second part:

> But if test_percent >=20 than we need a review_time of at least 4 hours to get a TRUE

What it says is that *in some cases* you pass the test with `feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 4`

You can pass with either `feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 2` or `feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 4`. The only difference is `test_percent`.

What the exercise text says is when `test_percent` is lower than `20`, you pass with `feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 2`, and when it's equal or higher than `20`, you pass with `feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 4`.

So if it's `test_percent < 20 and feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 2`, you pass. *Or* you pass when it's `test_percent >= 20 and feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 4`.

Thus,

```
(test_percent < 20 and feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 2) or (test_percent >= 20 and feel_prepared == True and review_time >= 4)
```

You can then apply distributive law and write

```
feel_prepared == True and ((test_percent < 20 and review_time >= 2) or (test_percent >= 20 and review_time >= 4))
```

You can also notice that when you `feel_prepared` and `review_time >= 4`, you always pass. But when `2 <= review_time < 4`, you pass only if `test_score < 20`:

```
feel_prepared == True and (review_time >= 4 or (review_time >= 2  and test_percent < 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem:

```py
test_percent = 19
review_time = 2
feel_prepared = True

statement = feel_prepared and ((test_percent >= 20 and review_time >=4) or (test_percent < 20 and review_time >=2))

print(statement) #True because test_percent < 20 and review_time >= 2

test_percent = 21
review_time = 2
feel_prepared = True

statement = feel_prepared and ((test_percent >= 20 and review_time >=4) or (test_percent < 20 and review_time >=2))

print(statement) #False because test_percent >= 20 and review_time < 4
```

Comment: Grazie Mille Domiziano

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is with the parenthesis, and fact that (test_percent < 20 or test_percent >= 20) always return True.

I don't know if I understood correctly all the cases, but I think this is the correct :)

```
print((prepared and review_time >=2 and test_percent < 20) or (prepared and review_time >=4 and test_percent >= 20)
```

Comment: Did you actually test this to see if the output is the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I obtained True for the case he told, and false for this case test_percent = 21
review_time = 2
feel_prepared = True, that only became true if review_time is 4 or higher